# Class Library Project not referenced in WebAPI Project using 3 tier architecture web application

Tags: asp.net-web-api, reference

I have a web application with n-tier architecture. All the POCO classes are in a class-library project named EntityFramework and the DBContext class named DB. And another project is WebAPI with all the API controllers. I added the following code in my WebAPI controller:

```
    using EntityFramework;
    namespace WebAPI
    {
     private DB db = new DB();
    }
```

Although I have added the reference of EntityFramework in WebAPI but still the line 'using EntityFramework;' has the red wavy underline and DB object cannot be created.

Comment: How can you declare your "DB" object at namespace level ? its not allowed in c# @Techy

Answer (score 1):

First of all read what the error message is saying and put it in your Post.

There could be a number of issues that cause that. A couple guesses from me:

1. You now have 2 dlls called EntityFramework and the code does not know which one you want to reference, hence the error.
2. the version of the dll does not match where you reference it. So, check both projects and make sure they both target the same framework version.

Do not call your DTO library EntityFramework, chances are you will get issues with the actual EntityFramework dll. Call it DTOs or Models, or anything else.

Comment: I still get this error 'the type or namespace name dbset<> could not be found'